# Jigsaw test dependencies in classpath: why is the superclass in another JAR not accessible?

Tags: maven, classpath, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I am currently testing to migrate an existing Java 8 (Maven) project to Java 9 / Jigsaw, using jdk9-ea+147 and maven-compiler-plugin 3.6.0.

I have converted the `src` directory to a module and left the `test` directory non-modular.

During `testCompile` I get an unexpected error:

> error: build() in ExtractedArtifactStoreBuilder is defined in an inaccessible class or interface

Of course I have checked that both the `ExtractedArtifactStoreBuilder` is public. `build()` is inherited from its (public) superclass and public as well. The code compiles and runs fine in JDK 8.

`ExtractArtifactStoreBuilder` is defined in a different 3rd partry JAR than its superclass, but Maven correctly puts both in the classpath. Confusingly, the superclass has the same classname (but resides in a different package)

As far as I can see, I should be able to access public inherited methods in my test code. So is this a bug in the jdk9 early access version?

---

**Edit:** hoping for better comprehensibility, here is a little abstraction of the involved JARs and classes, with less confusing naming and unimportant stuff left out (for the actual dependencies, see below):

**process.jar**

```
public ProcessStoreBuilder
    public ProcessStoreBuilder download(...) // returns "this"
    public ... build()
```

**mongo.jar**

```
public MongoStoreBuilder extends ProcessStoreBuilder
```

**src/test/java/ExampleTest**

```
mongoStoreBuilder.download(...).build()
//                              ^ breaks at compile time, saying that
//                              ProcessStoreBuilder#build() is not accessible
```

---

I have been able to reproduce the behavior in a minimal setup:

**pom.xml** (excerpt)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>9</source>
                <target>9</target>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <optimize>true</optimize>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <version>1.50.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.process</artifactId>
        <version>1.50.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**src/main/java/module-info.java**

```
module com.mycompany.example.testdependencyexample {}
```

**src/test/java/ExampleTest.java** (excerpt)

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    // both `download` and `build` are inherited from the superclass

    // the following does work
    // de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.config.ExtractedArtifactStoreBuilder
    ExtractedArtifactStoreBuilder easb =  new ExtractedArtifactStoreBuilder();
    easb.download(new DownloadConfigBuilder().build());
    easb.build();

    // but this does not
    // download returns the same instance but has the superclass as return type
    // de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.ExtractedArtifactStoreBuilder
    // the compiler can't see the `build` method of the superclass
    new ExtractedArtifactStoreBuilder()
            .download(new DownloadConfigBuilder().build())
            .build();

}
```

Comment: The involved classes and JARs are a little confusing. It would help if you summarized which class is in which JAR/module (including the test classes) and which scopes they have.

Comment: What is strange is that your module descriptor is empty. Doesn't your module depend on anything?

Comment: I agree very much, took me some time to figure out and summarize this one. I'll give it another go, hoping to make things clearer. The module descriptor is empty because the code is from the minimal setup I created to isolate the behavior. Of course the original application has more dependencies.

Comment: @Nicolai I have added a little abstraction above, I hope that clears things up. Thanks for the hint :)